# how do I find home directories that are writable by group or other?

Tags: bash, shell

I am really new to Bash Scripting so please bear with me if this question sounds stupid. I am also not too sure what to search on the internet.**What should I do if I need to write a shell script to list any directory where one user's home directory can be modified by some other user?** I am not able to understand what this '*modified by some other user means*'.Please help. Thanks !

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. What do you mean *one user's home directory can be modified by some other user*?

Comment: Read about file permissions. `man chmod` is one place to start, and look on the web. You need to learn how Unix file permissions work before you do this. Then read about the `find` command.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch . Thanks for replying. That is the exact thing I am not able to understand !

Comment: @Noob `find /home -type d -print | grep -v $(whoami)`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch . Sorry sir, did not understand that !

Comment: You can try this command `find /home -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -perm /022`.

Comment: @Noob The question isn't particularly good fit for SO. It sounds like a homework question, which is fine, but what seems to be an optimal answer would include a turorial into fs permissions, of which there are many online (just search something like `linux permissions` or `unix permissions`). As far as how you should approach the question, it's not impeccably worded, but the way I read it, you should do something like get all user home directories (parsing /etc/passwd is as good a method as any), and list all those that either have global write or other user access (e.g. in group) and write

Comment: Thanks @BroSlow , I will be careful next time onwards. I don't know why I got that negative vote though. The question wasn't too bad. And I'll go through your suggested method.

Comment: @Noob I didn't downvote it, but some people prefer to downvote rather than close. It is, in my opinion, too broad for SO and you should generally include a minimal attempted solution, especially if you're asking for homework help. I would look at a tutorial and play around with writing a `bash` script and if you can't get it to work post your attempted solution.

Comment: @BroSlow Haha , I am not saying you downvoted it. I just wanted to know how I could post better questions. Thanks for the suggestions !

Comment: Quick and dirty `cut -d: -f6 /etc/passwd | while read home; do if (( 0$(stat -c %a $home 2>/dev/null) & 022 )) > 0; then echo $home; fi; done`

Answer (score 3):

The very short answer to your question is: **no script needed, simply:**

```
ls -al /home
```

That will list for you all users and the respective permissions for each users home directory. Linux file permission are controlled by `10 bits` that represent **who** has access and **what**, if any, special permissions are associated with a given file. The permissions bits are usually represented for discussion as `drwxrwxrwx`. The first, or special, bit meaning is as follows:

```
     _: (unset) indicates a regular file with no special properties
     d: directory,
     l: link,
     s: the directory is setuid/setgid
     t: sticky bit
```

The next nine bits `rwxrwxrwx` (3 sets of `rwx`) control the access the `owner group world` has to the file in question. So who is the **owner** **group** or **world**? Let's look at an example from `ls -al /home`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  15 deborah users  4096 Mar 11  2011 deborah
```

Looking at the information we can separate the 10 bits and information as follow:

```
d  rwx  r-x  r-x  ..  deborah  users  ..... deborah
    |    |    |       \        \            \
  owner  |  world      owner    group        filename
       group
```

Above the special permission  bit is a `d` which indicates that the filename (at the far right **deborah**) is a directory. The first set of 3 bit specifies that the **owner (deborah)** has `r`ead, `w`rite and e`x`ecute permission on the file. Similarly, the next set of 3 specify that the **group (users)** has `r`ead and and e`x`ecute permission but no `w`rite permission. `NOTE: with a directory, the execute bit also control whether the (owner, group or world) can descend into the directory`. In like manner, the **world (everybody)** has the same permission as **group (users)**.

To manipulate the bits, you use the `chmod` (change mode) command. To manipulate the user or group, you use the `chown` (change owner) command. The `chown` command has simple basic usage, just specify the new `owner` and `group` separated by a colon `:`. For example to change the file shown above to be owned by user `david` and group `samba` the command would be `chown david:samba filename`

There are two ways to change the permissions or (mode) with `chmod`. You either specify the octal equivalent for special bit and the 3 sets of owner, group and world bits at once numerically. Example: to make the directory `rwx` for the **user** and **group** you would issue the command:

```
chmod 0775 filename    # to set all permissions as desired at once
```

The `0` simply stating no special bit settings for the directory, the first `7` indicating the binary `111` (or `rwx`) for the **user**, the second `7` indicating the same for the **group** and the final `5` indicating the **world** should have (binary `101`) `r_x` permissions. While not always required, it is recommended to provide the leading `0` even when there will be no change to the special permission bit to remove any ambiguity.

You can also use chmod with **+/-/=** `r`, `w`, `x` (for corresponding `rwx` bits) for `u`, `g`, or `o` `u`ser, `g`roup, or `o`wner permissions (you can shorcut using `a` for **all**). To put it all together and set the mode the same as shown above using octal bit, you would simply do:

```
chmod g+w filename      # to add the single write bit to group 'users'
```

Using this method, you may be required to make multiple calls to `chmod` to set all permission as required, but contrast using the octal permissions, you can set **all** permission fields in a single call.

Obviously there is much more to it than this, but for a good introduction, this should be enough to get you started managing permissions and ownership. (obviously this post also turned out way longer than initially anticipated, enjoy).

Comment: Helpful and nicely presented, but the OP was specifically asking for a _script_. To round out your post, however, I suggest adding links to resources for the things you do _not_ explain here (`setuid`, sticky bit, ...). The statement `the execute bit also controls whether the (owner, group or world) can descend into the directory` is somewhat ambiguous in that it could be interpreted to mean that for directories it controls _more_ than the ability to recurse into its subtree (whereas, I presume, the `also` refers to the _bit_ doing double duty: distinct meanings based on file type).

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the comment. I NOTED IN BOLD the execute bit's control on descent in to the directory in the original directly under the diagram. That usually catches people. I guess I should have wrapped the `ls` command in a loop and followed it with a `test -w`, but it was apparent the OP needed to start a few steps earlier in understanding ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The:

> where one user's home directory can be modified by some other user?

can be:

1. if the user1 is in the same group as user2 *AND* the home directory is group-writable, or
2. if the user has world-writable directory

You really need understand how unix-like permissions works. (or in wider context - how ACLs works in general)

For the (partial) solution (many ways - one of them is the next):

1. you can get the path of home directories from the `/etc/passwd` file.
2. can read them in a cycle, (filter the `/etc/passwd` with the `cut` command), and
3. test, if they're writable for you (for this, read the man page about the shell builtins `if` and the command `test` alias `[`.