# Commands without sudo in bash do not work

Tags: bash, sudo, permission-denied

I am running a bash script and these commands in the script will not work without sudo in front of them. The script.sh is located in a folder such as /jobs/script.sh

Example of commands I am trying to run in the script.sh -

- mv /var/app/myapp /var/app/myapp.old
- rm file.tar.gz
- tar -xzf /home/ubuntu/file.tar.gz -C /var/app/

All the above work if I add sudo in front of them.

I am trying to figure out what permissions are required for them to work without adding sudo in the script.

I have tried giving the script.sh rwx permissions and changing owner to root.

I'm learning permissions in linux, so I'm new to this. Basically what permission should the script.sh have so that I dont have to use sudo in the bash file? Any insight would greatly help.

Comment: You need to set permissions for what the script accesses, not the script itself.

Comment: This is not about the script permission, this is about the permission of the user you run it with on the files you try to move, remove and archive.

Comment: Which user owns `/var/app`? Which owns the directory that `file.tar.gz` is in?

Comment: That said, _in general_, this isn't a Stack Overflow question, not being specific to software development -- [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is better suited to general "how do I use UNIX?" subjects. All of these commands will fail in the same way if run as a user with insufficient permissions whether or not there's a script involved; thus, it's not a script-development-specific question.

Comment: A cliff's notes version of  Linux file ownership and permission can be found in [how do I find home directories that are writable by group or other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24622636/3422102) The likely problem in your case are the files in `/var/app` and `/home/ubuntu` are not owned by, or have the same group as the user who runs `/jobs/script.sh`. The script will be run as the user who starts it. (if started by cron or systemd, it will likely be a system user). If the script running under `auser` tries to access or modify files owned by `buser` without world permissions - sudo is needed

Answer (score 0):

When you run `sudo <some command>`, then `<some command>` is run by the root user (Super user do). The reason you might *need* to run any command using `sudo` is because the permissions on the files that command reads/writes/executes are such that only the "Super user" (root) has that permission.

When executing the command `mv fileA fileB`, the executing user would need:

- Write permission to `fileB` if `fileB` already existed
- Write permission to the directory containing `fileB`

Comment: One does not necessarily need permission to read a file to rename it (if source and destination are on the same filesystem, and one has write access to both directories, one can rename a file one can neither read nor write).

Answer (score 0):

From what you said it’s most likely you want read and write permissions you can achieve this with `chmod`

```
Chmod +[permission] filename
```

(+ is used to add permission you can also use - instead to remove it)
Where permissions can be:

```
r  —> read 
w—> write 
x —>excecute
```

... and more

FOR EXAMPLE: it seems you write permissions for the first file so :

```
chmod +w /var/app/myapp
```

Will fix problem