# How do I make permissions so the user is the only one that can modify?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, chmod, user-permissions

My script is creating a folder for an user and now, i'm trying to make my user the only one that can modify his folder and that nobody else can do anything to it.

Comment: Hi, `chmod 700` would grant permissions to the user only. The octal value 730 grants rwx permissions to the user and wx to the user's group.

Comment: See [how do I find home directories that are writable by group or other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24622636/3422102) for extended discussion of Linux permission bits.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want 750, meaning that only the user has all permissisons, the group has read permissions and everyone else has none. With 730 the group can write, but not read.
It also looks like you have a typo in `sudo chmod 730 /home/${tableauParam[$compteur]}` and are modifying a non-existing directory

Comment: Also, when I execute this line from the previous loop I mentionned: `sudo useradd -m -b /home/${tableauParam[$compteur]} ${tableauParam[$compteur]} -G $1`. It shows the same result as man useradd while doing the command. Whats the problem.

Comment: @drseek That's a "usage" message; it means that you're running `useradd` with incorrect arguments (and `useradd` is helpfully explaining what arguments you *can* use). My guess is that you need to put the `-G $1` before the username, or maybe double-quote your variables (run your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net)!). Also, it looks like you're using the `-b` option incorrectly.

Comment: `750` - the group has **read and execute** permission. `740` would give user full permission and group **read** permission. `730` gives group **write and execute**  permission.