# bash file not running caused by permission error

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a bash file and can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly.

The commands I'm trying to run are:

```
Streaming Command Failed!
jcros001@lena:~/Topic2$ ./script_test
bash: ./script_test: Permission denied
jcros001@lena:~/Topic2$
```

The bash file I created is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


hadoop fs -copyFromLocal docs ./docs

mahout seqdirectory -i docs -o docs-seqfiles -c UTF-8 -chunk 5
```

Comment: The script file does not have the eXecutable attribute. So use either `/bin/bash script_test` or run first `chmod 755 script_test` and then can be used `./script_test`.

Comment: Like Mofi said, you need to change it to be executable.  There's a very nice answer from user Ravexina [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/932719/55321) which shows (with a pretty picture) the different ways you can use `chmod`.

Comment: @user2946746 : In addition to what Mofi correctly said: If you decide to invoke it using `bash scriptname`  and therefore don't need x-permissions, you still need read permisssion.  You can do i.e. `stat script_test` to see the permissions of your script.

Comment: Or if you are more comfortable with the `-r`, `-w`, `-x` notation, `chmod +x script_test` (personally I prefer providing the full permission octets, e.g. `chmd 0755 script_test`) See [Full write-up on file/directory permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24622636/3422102)