# Providing permissions to all the users in Linux

Tags: linux, file-permissions

How to give all permissions to all the users in Linux? I know how to give permissions to single users but I don't know how to do it for all or multiple users. I'm kinda new at this.

Comment: Linux file permissions come in 3-groups of `rwx`, the first is the owner (user - UID), the second is for members of the group (GID) and the last set of `rwx` is for others (world - everybody else). So to give ALL Linux users permissions, you need to set the 3rd group of `rwx` to what you need using `chmod`. The permissions on the directory containing the file must have `x` set for others (allowing others to descend into the directory) to access the file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin so basically my directory should be `drwxrwxr-x` and my file should be `rwxrw-rwx`, right?

Comment: Yes, minimum for "other" to descent into the directory and read the file. `chmod 0775 thedir` will set the permission as you show. Each `rwx` can be set as `1` for `x`, `2` for `w` or `4` for `r`, `6` for `rw` or `7` for `rwx` or `5` for `r_x` (e.g. `5` in binary is `101`, `6` is `110`, `7` is `111` and so forth, each bit corresponding to the `r`, `w` and `x` permission.) the leading `0` in `0775` is for special permissions `setuid`, `setgid` or `sticky-bit`. So if you wanted user to have `rwx` and group and other to have read and execute, it would be `chmod 0755 filename`.

Comment: See [how do I find home directories that are writable by group or other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24622636/3422102) for a full write-up.

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidC.Rankin. This is informative and descriptive, and I was able to change the permissions as well.

Comment: Good deal. Good luck with you Linux learning. There is no finer OS once you make friends with it. If the linked answer helped -- you can always upvote it `:)`

Comment: Thank you. It's a journey that will take its own sweet time. And yes, I was planning to do that but I'm not sure how to get there, I'm new to stack as well. lol

Comment: Just click on the link in the comment and it will take you right there. Learning anything worth while is more a journey than a race. So don't try (or think you can) learn it all in a semester, year or several. I've used Linux for more the 2 decades and I still learn something new every day.

Comment: Okay, got it. And yes, you are right about it. Thank you for your insights. And please keep helping us like this, we really need more people like you.
Update: I can't upvote it, it says I need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote. But it has recorded my feedback

Answer (score 0):

In linux, each directory and file has 2 ownership info

- user owner: who *created* the file
- group owner: an entire group of user *owning* the file

And each directory and file has 3 set of permissions

- *user owner*
- *group owner*
- *other users*  : note: this is not 'all users' but 'other users', so if you are the user owner or member of group owner you are NOT part of other users

That said

- you can give a permission to 'all others users' using last set of rwx permissions
- you can give a permission to 'all users' using each set of permissions so both the owner and all members of the group owner and all other users can do what you want

| Be aware: do not use 777 (rwxrwxrwx) if is not absolutely necessary ! It opens to security concerns